# How to look up the information using another table as a reference

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a mysql database, "points" and "userpoints".
e.g

Points:

```
id  | pointvalue  | message
----------------------------
1   | 5           | comment
```

Userpoints:

```
id | uid |pid | timestamp
-------------------------
89 | 5   | 1  | timestamp
```

How will I get the sum of the points in the userpoints table when it is being linked by the pid in userpoints?

Using a mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT up.uid, SUM(p.pointvalue) total_points
     FROM Userpoints up
LEFT JOIN Points p
       ON up.pid = p.id
    WHERE up.uid = 5;
```

Comment: How would I select the points where uid = a variable? So the sum of points for a person who has the uid 5 or maybe 10?

Comment: @Matthew: Edited the answer to add the `WHERE` clause. If you are going to use it with a `WHERE` clause, then you don't need the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`select sum(p.pointvalue) from userpoints up left join points p on up.pid = p.id group by up.uid`